# Customers pay without ever leaving your website using Paypal

Tags: paypal

My customer give me this link https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/compare-business-products and want me to implement feature "Customers pay without ever leaving your website" with "Advanced" product.

My question is what method should I use to archive this?
Currently I'm using method "Express Checkout" with IPN to fulfill payment process.

And beside, must I change anything in my Paypal account (upgrade account, turn on any API... ) to enable this feature?

I can not google this out, any helps will be appreciate!
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Payments Advanced is a separate product from Express Checkout.  It's part of the PayFlow API, so you need to have an account setup at http://manager.paypal.com.  If you don't already have this then you're probably on a "regular" PayPal account, and you would indeed need to get them to switch you over to PayFlow.  Simply applying for Payments Advanced should trigger that action for you, and then they'll send you login credentials for your PayPal Manager.

With Payments Advanced you make an API to obtain a secure token from the PayPal server on-the-fly, and then you use that token within some basic HTML code similar to a standard button.

This causes the full checkout form to be displayed within an i-frame on your page.  When the user checks out there they'll never leave your site.

There's a good 2-part video on YouTube that covers this in more detail.

[Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyiv3ndRcZI) | [Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Z5v-ha0YII)

You can also find [plenty of documentation about it](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#ppa) at X.com.

Comment: Thank you so much, things are clearer. But as the document says, PayPal Advanced is just available in US only(my customer is in Switzerland) so maybe I have to choose PayPal Pro. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I'm in swizerland too what did you finally chose for the account type in order to do what you wanted. And do you still use IPN afterward? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, Payments Pro is only available in the US, UK, and Canada.