# paypal customize checkout page which use paypal payment only

Tags: php, paypal

I want to include paypal checkout without leaving website i develop for a client. i'm using the developer account. what paypal option or api do i need to use here? (there are so many api's which confuses me)

and also i need to customize the checkout page style and look, so that users can only pay through paypal accounts (**not enter credit card details**).

i have reviewed the following questions but couldn't find a proper solution..

[stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391928/customers-pay-without-ever-leaving-your-website-using-paypal)

Comment: I'm a little confused.  First you say you want to do a checkout without leaving your site, but then you say you want to customize checkout so that users can only pay through PayPal..??  You can't do both of those things.  If users are paying with PayPal they will be redirected through PayPal so they can login.  So which one do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a similar question to yours:

[From Stack PayPal Redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243089/how-can-a-buyer-without-being-redirected-to-paypal-complete-the-transaction/23256532#23256532)

You cannot use PayPal Standard and stay on your website. You either need to get setup with PayPal Payments Advanced or PayPal Payments Pro.

Using PayPal Payments Advanced you can use an iFrame that uses the PayPal Hosted Page while giving the appearance of staying on your website.

Here is the getting started guide: 
[PayPal Payments Advanced Getting Started Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/)

Comment: is it possible to create a sandbox paypal advance account for the development testing?

Comment: Yes, you can begin the application and create a test account. You will create a Test PayPal Manager Account [PayPal Advanced Setup](https://registration.paypal.com/onboardingPage.do?bundleType=C2&country=US&partner=PayPal)